# SQL convert String date of style d-MMM-yyyy to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, sql-server-2012

I'm importing a CSV file and one of the fields is a non-standard date string with entries like `7-Dec-2021`

Any ideas for to convert this into a `DATETIME` object that I can insert into my SQL table? Standard `CAST`/`CONVERT` didn't work.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60

Comment: You said version 15 a second ago. Now you're using 2012; that's version 11...

Comment: Sorry, @Larnu. I wrongly posted my local MS SQL version and not the clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRY_CONVERT` seems to be working here:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '7-Dec-2021');  -- 2021-12-07 00:00:00.000
```

**Edit:**

Your input date almost matches format mask 106, once we replace the dashes with spaces.  Consider this solution:

```sql
SELECT dt, CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(dt, '-', ' '), 106) AS dt_out
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs `2021-12-07 00:00:00.000` for `dt_out` on SQL Server 2014, and should behave the same way on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Sadly that just returned Null

Comment: Well my answer is working for SQL Server 2014, [check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8d12ee49686f12196e08ea997c9cb1c9).

Comment: Regional settings issue?

Comment: I suspect that the OP is using a language that isn't English based, and that as a results, `dec` isn't a recognised month.

Comment: @Larnu That must be the explanation, but sadly I am fairly weak on TSQL and I don't know how to correct my answer for that.  Maybe you have some ideas and can post something?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen it seems to work on 2014 but not 2012. That might be the issue.

Comment: @Bugz I might have a way to do this using plain `CONVERT()`, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am *guessing* that you are using a `LOGIN` where its language isn't English based, and as a result `'Dec'` (and/or other months) isn't recognised as a valid month name.

You can specify your language to be used for the batch and then `CONVERT`:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,'7-Dec-2021',106);
```